# IE only applying SOME external css style sheets

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a site that renders correctly on all browsers except IE Edge, 10, 9, etc (I'm on a Mac, but using Remote Desktop to view a PC environment).

The problem I'm having is that only one of the two custom CSS stylesheets are being read (not counting the foundation.css file). So, the top half of the page renders correctly, but the bottom half is using a separate style sheet because it's using a "timeline" type layout, and it made sense to keep that load of CSS separate for ease of making edits.

I've tried everything I can find regarding different meta tags relating to IE, and I've tried combining the two stylesheets, since the first one seems to be read correctly.

The only other thing I can find is people saying that it may just be a simple missing div tag or something that's breaking it, but I ran it through the http://validator.w3.org/, and the only errors that came up were related to missing alt text on images.

Any help at all would be appreciated! Here's a bit of the code in the head, if that helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Customer Outreach | Ford Takata Airbag Recall Information Center</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/timeline.css">
 </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I had only run the HTML through the W3C validator... just now I ran the CSS through the CSS validator, and it gave me an error for this line:

```
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.…nts='0,0 32,0 16,24' style='fill: rgb%28138, 138, 138%29'></polygon></svg>);
```

The code came from a third-party site for this "timeline" I'm working on, so I don't know the original need for it, but once I deleted that, the site rendered perfect on IE. Here's a screenshot of what the validator said:

[image: validator]

Not sure if this specific fix will help anyone, but I came across this because I got a couple suggestions that the syntax in the CSS file was probably the culprit, even a missing bracket or semicolon. That wasn't the case, but always check that first. :)

Comment: You can try putting the data url in double quotes. `background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.…nts='0,0 32,0 16,24' style='fill: rgb(138, 138, 138)'></polygon></svg>");` Not sure if it helps for IE, but I'm sure it won't do any harm for the other browsers.

Comment: From your last post, I can see that you had solved the issue and posted your solution. It will be helpful to other community members in future, If you try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer after 24 hrs when it will be available to mark. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, I have tried a couple times to mark my answer as accepted, but still not available to do so.